# PHP array_merge rekeying -- how's it work?

Tags: php, array-merge

I had a head-scratcher yesterday.

Basically I had an associative array of some data with string keys(containing numeric values, but still, quoted strings) to go in a `<select>` box as options. I wanted to prepend a placeholder value to the select box's options.

I attempted to use array_merge:

```
$placeholder = "Month";
$source = array
(
    '01' => '01 - January',
    '02' => '02 - February',
    '03' => '03 - March',
    '04' => '04 - April',
    '05' => '05 - May',
    '06' => '06 - June',
    '07' => '07 - July',
    '08' => '08 - August',
    '09' => '09 - September',
    '10' => '10 - October',
    '11' => '11 - November',
    '12' => '12 - December'
);

$source = array_merge(array('' => $placeholder), $source);
```

And I was seeing weird results -- the resultant `$source` array was similar to the following:

```
(
    '' => 'Month',
    '01' => '01 - January',
    '02' => '02 - February',
    '03' => '03 - March',
    '04' => '04 - April',
    '05' => '05 - May',
    '06' => '06 - June',
    '07' => '07 - July',
    '08' => '08 - August',
    '09' => '09 - September',
    0 => '10 - October',
    1 => '11 - November',
    2 => '12 - December'
);
```

Note that it began using what appear to be auto-incrementing integer keys for October through December for some reason.

I can replace the array_merge call with this:

```
$source = array('' => $placeholder) + $source;
```

And the array doesn't get rekeyed and everything is fine, but I don't understand what's happening under the scenes in the `array_merge` case.

Can anyone please explain what was happening to my array keys when I used `array_merge`? Thanks!

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected my array keys to be maintained.

Comment: From the docs: "Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero." I guess that '01' is not determined as being numeric by the function's implementation. (c.f. `is_numeric('01')`)

Comment: `is_numeric('01')` and `is_numeric('10')` both return true values -- why would the key for '10' change after the merge but not the key for '01'?

Comment: Because whatever logic the implementation uses behind the scenes is not the same logic as used by `is_numeric`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem doesn't come from the `array_merge()` function.

If you print `$source` before merging, you'll have this :

```
array(12) {
  ["01"]=>
  string(12) "01 - January"
  ["02"]=>
  string(13) "02 - February"
  // ...
}
```

Try to rename your first key `'01'` to `'1'`, You will have the following return :

```
array(12) {
  [1]=>
  string(12) "01 - January"
  ["02"]=>
  string(13) "02 - February"
  // ...
}
```

PHP auto convert your key to integer. But I can't say you why It does it.

**EDIT :**

I have found the answer on php.net ([PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) :

> A key may be either an integer or a string. If a key is the standard
>   representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8"
>   will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08").
>   Floats in key are truncated to integer. The indexed and associative
>   array types are the same type in PHP, which can both contain integer
>   and string indices.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained very clearly in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> Don't forget that numeric keys will be renumbered!

The keys not starting with a `'0'` are seen as numeric by PHP -- and thus renumbered.

Comment: but `is_numeric('01')` and `is_numeric('10')` both return true values

Comment: PHP is looking for a literal integer not just a "numeric" value, thus 1 != "1"

Comment: Hmm, strange indeed. There's some stuff in [the comments](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#100240) about this as well.

Comment: Aknosis -- then why is '10' a literal integer even though it's quoted?

Comment: **-1** because there is no renumber in an associative array. PHP replaces `'10'` to `10` when array is declared and not when the `array_merge()` is processed.

Comment: @Rijk : Yes in case of numeric key but not in an associative array ;).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points in the docs lead to the explanation for this:

From [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge):

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero.

And from [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> A *key* may be either an integer or a string. If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. *"8"* will be interpreted as *8*, while *"08"* will be interpreted as *"08"*).

This explains why the first keys are not seen as numeric keys, and hence they are not re-indexed. Your other keys are seen as numeric keys.